# SQLAlchemy Sessions Multithreaded Issues

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy for running database queries on a managed postgres instance on GCP Cloud SQL.
I am having dramatiq task queue which can run max 20 tasks concurrently at once.

And a single task that runs would do multiple calls and that too on multiple threads to database to retrieve data from it.

Now first of all I was calling the function that gets data from database by using 24 worker threads, till that it worked fine but after making it 100, it started getting issues.

First of all I got this error -

```
TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30.
```

I tried to search on internet and found that increasing max_overflow would fix it. Also I found that I can make it unlimited by saying -1, which then I applied.

Here was my original arguments for create_engine -

```py
engine = create_engine(
    environment_resolver.get("DB_URL"),
    echo=environment_resolver.environment not in ["staging", "prod"],
    poolclass=QueuePool,
    pool_size=5,
    max_overflow=10,
    pool_recycle=3600,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    connect_args={
        'connect_timeout': 60,
        "keepalives": 1,
        "keepalives_idle": 30,
        "keepalives_interval": 10,
        "keepalives_count": 5,
    }
)
```

After doing this I got this error -

```
FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Then I even tried using scoped_session, but that also didnt fix the error. So I am really confused currently as to what is happening. Please anyone help me in fixing this.